# Just to Clarify for the Isomers of C5H12O

Tags: isomers

Are these the isomers to $\ce{C5H12O}$? If so what makes them so different from each other?

- pentanol
- 2-pentanol
- 3-pentanol
- 3-methyl-2-butanol
- 2-methylbutanol
- methyl butyl ether
- methyl isobutyl ether
- methyl-t-butyl ehter
- methyl-s-butyl ether
- ethylpropyl ether
- ethylisopropyl ether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corresponding to $\ce{C5H12O}$  there will be a total of 14 structural isomers.

***8 isomers with alcohol functional group:***

(1) $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH2CH2OH}$  : n-pentanol

(2) $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH(OH)CH3}$  : 2-pentanol

(3) $\ce{CH3CH2CH(OH)CH2CH3}$  : 3-pentanol

(4) $\ce{CH3CH2C(CH3)(OH)CH3}$  : 2-methyl-2-butanol

(5) $\ce{CH3CH2CH(CH3)CH2OH}$  : 2-methyl-1-butanol

(6) $\ce{CH3CH(OH)CH(CH3)CH3}$  : 3-methyl-2-butanol

(7) $\ce{CH3CH(CH3)CH2CH2OH}$  : 3-methyl-1-butanol

(8) $\ce{CH3C(CH3)2CH2OH}$  : 2,2-dimethyl-1-propanol

***6 isomers with ether functional group:***

(1) $\ce{CH3CH2CH2CH2-O-CH3}$  : methyl butyl ether

(2) $\ce{CH3CH2CH2-O-CH2CH3}$  : ethyl propyl ether

(3) $\ce{CH3CH(CH3)CH2-O-CH3}$  : methyl isobutyl ether

(4) $\ce{CH3CH2-O-CH(CH3)CH3}$  : ethyl isopropyl ether

(5)  $\ce{CH3CH2CH(CH3)-O-CH3}$ :methyl sec-butyl ether

(6) $\ce{(CH3)3-C-O-CH3}$ : methyl tert-butyl ether